# Why is the loop not iterating for compounding investment calculation in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, calculation

I'm writing a function to calculate investment return over period of years. However, the function seems to be only able to calculate for one year. If the `totalyears` is more than 1, the loop as shown below is not iterating and it returns wrong value.

```js
const calc = (initial, monthlyContribution, totalyears, annualisedReturn) => {
    let sum = initial;
    for (i = 0; i < totalyears; i++) { // ISSUE: THIS NOT LOOPING WHEN totalyears > 1
        let balance = sum;
        let totalBalance = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            totalBalance = totalBalance + balance;
            balance = balance + monthlyContribution;
        }
        sum = balance + (totalBalance / 12) * (annualisedReturn / 100);
    }
    return sum;
};

console.log(calc(0, 100, 2, 10)); // This return 1255 which is wrong
```

Comment: debug your `i` variable

Comment: you are redefining your `i` variable in the second loop, pick a different var name

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same global variable for both loops. `i` will have the value 12 when leaving the inner loop, thus the condition of the outer loop will be false

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable "i" in the inner loop and you are not declaring it again.
So when you start the loop with i=0, your inner loop will first make i=0 again, then it will increase until i=12, and then the same variable is used in the first loop, so it will go from 0 to 12, skipping iterations. Use "i, j,k" for nested loops.
Something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `let`, you can re-use the name `i` with no issue because it'll be block-scoped. But in general I would advise meaningful iterator names. `for( let year=0; year<...`

Comment: You are right, using let we can re-use the name, I used "i" and "j" for better readability